# Accessing VIM in Digital Ocean cuts off part of file

Tags: debugging, vim, gruntjs, digital-ocean, meanjs

I tried running grunt to run a MEAN web app and received an ILLEGAL TOKEN in lodash.js, a file which has ~4000 lines. I went to debug the error on line 2220 and received a different syntax error on line 2238, but the VIM editor in Digital Ocean says that the file is only 2228 lines, and even using 'G' to get to the end of the file takes me to 2228. How do I access the rest of the file to debug when the editor thinks that the file is only 2228 lines?

Comment: What's the output of `$ wc -l < lodash.js`?

Comment: The output is '2228'

Comment: You can jump straight to line 2220 using `vim -c :2220 lodash.js`. I'm confused though, in the same paragraph you say lodash.js has about 4000 lines, and later that it is only 2028, and in comments it seems to be 2228. Where did you get the idea it was 4000 lines?

Comment: Because that's how many lines it is in my github repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug was related to some dependencies not being resolved in npm install. Issue resolved by increasing RAM of droplet.